# Swipe touch events are caught by the browser not by my website

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, jquery-ui-touch-punch

On my horizontally scrolling website I have these functions that handle swiping:

```
$("body").mousedown(function (event) {
  ....
});

$(document).mouseup(function (event) {
  ....
});
```

If distance and time from mouse down to mouse up are within the tresholds, it is a swipe. A swipe will scroll the website one screen width. This works excellent when I do it with the mouse.

I have included jquery.touch-punch to treat touch events as mouse events. But on the touch monitor I have connected to the pc a touch would be handled very differently by the browser (chrome). Swiping right/left goes backward/forward through the browser history. The mouse up/down events are never triggered on my website.

Am I using touch-punch wrong?
Or is it a browser behaviour I can turn off? 
Or is it a windows 7 thing?